# Can Apache NiFi configure logback.xml file to send logs to remote server over UDP?

Tags: udp, logback, apache-nifi

I have an Apache NiFi instance that needs to log messages to a remote Graylog server. I want the outputs to nifi-app.log, nifi-bootstrap.log, and nifi-user.log to all be sent to this server, as well as their default local policy.

I'm trying to get the logs to the server over UDP, as the network configuration requires UDP connections.

My questions:

1. Does logback support sending logs over UDP?
2. If so, what does that configuration look like?
3. Is there a better way to configure Apache NiFi to send it's logs over UDP?

Comment: And who is a receiver of udp messages?

Comment: @daggett Who is the receiver in my setup? A Graylog server. There is effectively a network diode between the NiFi server and the Graylog server, so UDP is the only option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Logback does not provide an out-of-the-box UDP appender so you would need to add the necessary JARs for some UDP appender, possibly the logstash one:

https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder

This might work, but adding JARs to NiFi's lib directory is a bit dangerous as they end up on the classpath of all NiFi processors and could have unintended consequences.

Other options...

1) Use TCP

logback already has an socket appender provided:
https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SocketAppender

2) Use a separate NiFi instance that is used to monitor the logs of the first NiFi instance. The flow would be TailFile -> PutUDP, where TailFile points at nifi-app.log of the first NiFi.

Comment: Thanks - I was worried that there wasn't out of the box UDP support, and want to avoid adding additional dependencies. Since TCP isn't an option I'll need a work around.

I like your recommendation of an additional NiFi instance, although I'm curious if there is a reason why you recommend an additional instance, instead of a different thread of processors in the same instance...Would that cause problems?

Comment: You can definitely tail the logs from the same NiFi instance, but it is creating a circular loop where if the TailFile or PutUDP generates logs, then they run more to pick up their own logs, it might work ok though

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple solution of using LogMessage processor & make sure all the LogMessage log entries goes to a particular file (flow-events.log) & then tail on it?

```
<appender name="EVENTS_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir}/flow-events.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir}/flow-events_%d.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{40} %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
<logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.LogMessage" level="INFO" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="EVENTS_FILE" />
</logger>
```